# How to reduce command with .replace and problems in create function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in which I would like to replace the 0, 1 encoding with 'yes' and 'no' in some columns that I've selected. Some df columns have this encoding and so I wrote the following command:

```
dados_trabalho = dados_trabalho.replace({"ASSINTOM": {0: "Sim", 1 : "Não"}}).replace({"DOR ATIPICA": {0: "Sim", 1 : "Não"}}).replace({"IAM": {0: "Sim", 1 : "Não"}}).replace({"HAS": {0: "Sim", 1 : "Não"}}).replace({"DM": {0: "Sim", 1 : "Não"}}).replace({"DISPLIP": {0: "Sim", 1 : "Não"}}).replace({"DOR TIPICA": {0: "Sim", 1 : "Não"}})
```

It runs correctly and replaces the columns identified by the new encoding, but I would like to know if there is a way to summarize this formula so that the script does not get huge.

I tried to create the function:

```
def change_columns (df):
    c = df.columns
    df = df.replace ({c: {0: "Yes", 1: "No"}})
```

The problem is when I enter the dataframe in this function the following error occurs:

```
change_columns (df)

TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-141-43eb9316b19b> in <module>
----> 1 change_columns (df)

<ipython-input-140-9fbbd4e9e293> in change_columns (df)
      1 def change_columns (df):
      2 c = df.columns
----> 3 df = df.replace ({c: {0: "Yes", 1: "No"}})

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in __hash __ (self)
   2060
   2061 def __hash __ (self):
-> 2062 raise TypeError ("unhashable type:% r"% type (self) .__ name__)
   2063
   2064 def __setitem __ (self, key, value):

TypeError: unhashable type: 'Index'
```

I'm starting with Python and so I think I'm forgetting something.

I changed a few things in the code and it worked. But the problem is that it applies the function in all df columns. How do I apply the function only on the columns I want and not for all columns?

```
def change_columns(df):
    for i in df.columns:
        df = df.replace({i: {0: "Sim", 1 : "Não"}})
    return df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you created (`change_columns(df)`), looks like it is trying to perform the replace on all the columns.  If this was your intention, you don't need any special function or chained method calls.  All you need is:

```
dados_trabalho = dados_trabalho.replace({0: "Sim", 1 : "Não"})
```

In order to only replace the 0's and 1's from some of the columns, you will need to tell the function which columns you want to perform the replacement on.  For example:

```
import pandas

def change_columns(df, cols):
    for col_name in cols:
        df = df.replace({col_name: {0:'yes', 1:'no'}})
    return df

# create sample data
df = pandas.DataFrame([[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]])
print('Starting DataFrame:')
print(df)

# define columns to do the replacement
columns_to_replace = [0, 2, 3]
# perform the replacement
df = change_columns(df, columns_to_replace)

# see the result
print('After processing DataFrame: ')
print(df)
```

Running the code above should produce the result:

```
Starting DataFrame:
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  0  0  1  0  1  1
1  1  0  1  0  1  0
After processing DataFrame:
     0  1   2    3  4  5
0  yes  0  no  yes  1  1
1   no  0  no  yes  1  0
```